# how to use ~/.ssh/config with Windows/PuTTY?

Tags: configuration, git, putty, gitlab

How can I use `~/.ssh/config` with Windows/PuTTY? Are PuTTY settings stored in the registry? I wish to have my PuTTY settings in `git`. So it needs to be a human readable text file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because The question appears to ask if Putty settings are store in the registry, this is a unlix/linux forum.

Comment: @XTian - PuTTY is a Windows and Linux application. Shown here: http://www.linuxtechi.com/install-putty-in-ubuntu/. Wikipedia page lists it as both too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY. Granted the OP is asking in the title w/ "Windows/PuTTY" so it's unclear if they this Q is targeted to Windows or Linux but this Q does have some merit.

Comment: In windows's world putty setting are store in registry, finding where, using google, should be easy. you basically export anything under Simon_Tathman (not sure of spelling tho).

Comment: On a side note, what do you intend to put under git ? ~/.ssh/config ? or dump of putty registry ?

Comment: Might be useful to this Q: this Perl script `pwin2lin.pl`: https://code.google.com/p/pwin2lin/. " simple PERL script to convert Windows PuTTY sessions to Linux PuTTY sessions." - Example of it in use here: https://mdinh.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/migrating-windows-putty-registry-to-linux/.

Comment: @slm tks for the clarification. @fyodor, Please help by clarifying your question, I may have misunderstood, but I read that your client is on windows and your server is linux, `~/ssh/config` is used by linux clients, the linux server is configured with `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ? Windows PuTTY doesn not currently support configuration via files, although there is a work-around mentioned in their documentation. See Section 4.28 http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/puttydoc.txt

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question still appears to ask about configuring Windows/PuTTY.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can! But it's another path where the Putty settings are stored. Where exactly the Putty configuration is stored is system dependant, but you can use a PuTTY session name just as if you would use a hostname for ssh to use that with git, at least with the git port for windows. That way you can set the auto-login user or other session features with the PuTTY client, save a session under a name you can remember and use the saved session name as a git host.

Git for Windows can use both, an integrated ssh client and the putty client. I never tried that on linux. There are several guides how to use that, when you search the internet.

Comment: I've tried this on Windows and it did work. I've managed to access my Amazon Web Services EC2 instance using PuTTY's `plink.exe` and entering only `>plink.exe saved-session-name` on ConEmu.

Comment: That's why I posted it, what did you expected ;)

Comment: I've posted it for it may help the question be opened :)